# clearing newline char from gtk.Textbuffer

Tags: gtk, pygtk

I have a gtk.TextBuffer which is supposed to be cleared after pressing Enter, similar to the input box on most chat programs. I'm just setting the buffer back to a blank string.  The newline character from Enter isn't removed though, and a blank line ends up above the cursor during the next input. Moving the cursor to the first gtk.Iter doesn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `"gobject.connect()"` callback is called before the default handler. You need to use `"gobject.connect_after()"`.

```
def insert_text_cb(text_buffer, position, text, lenght):
    if text == '\n':
        text_buffer.set_text('')

text_view = gtk.TextView()
text_view.get_buffer().connect_after('insert-text', insert_text_cb)
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you're trigger on the proper event? Also try connecting it after.